# Stop inputted text from one UITextView within a prototype cell adding to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6, uitextview

I have a weird issue, I can't get to the bottom of. I have a UITableView with various prototype cells depending on content stored in a mutable array. It works something like this:

```
    if([currentHandout.content[indexPath.row - 3] isKindOfClass: [objHandoutSubtitle class]]){
        cellId =@"CellHandoutSubtitle";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

        ..
    }
    else if([currentHandout.content[indexPath.row  - 3] isKindOfClass: [objHandoutParagraph class]]){
        cellId =@"CellHandoutGeneral";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

        ..
    }
    else if([currentHandout.content[indexPath.row  - 3] isKindOfClass: [objHandoutQuote class]]){
        cellId =@"CellHandoutQuote";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

        ..
    }
    else if([currentHandout.content[indexPath.row  - 3] isKindOfClass: [objHandoutSimpleQuestion class]]){
        cellId =@"CellHandoutSimpleQuestion";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UILabel *questionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        questionLabel.text = questionText;

        UITextView *theTextView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        theTextView.tag = indexPath.row + 100;
            theTextView.delegate = self;

        ..
    }
```

The problem is when  I add text to the UITextView in a CellHandoutSimpleQuestion cell it repeats the user input into another cell further below it, as shown in the image below, does anyone know why?

[image: repeating answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you are reusing the cell's UITextView. To avoid that you need to store the UITextView's text in a property of your models and also set that text on the last bit

```
...
else if([currentHandout.content[indexPath.row  - 3] isKindOfClass: [objHandoutSimpleQuestion class]]){
    cellId =@"CellHandoutSimpleQuestion";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *questionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    questionLabel.text = questionText;

    UITextView *theTextView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    theTextView.tag = indexPath.row + 100;
        theTextView.delegate = self;
        the.TextView.text = yourModelForTheCell.textViewText;
    ..
}
```

If you have need to support editing you have to update the property for the correspondent model object on the delegate method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:`

Comment: Thank you, this works well. The answer below from Skyler got me going but this fixed the issue of losing the text when I scroll the cell off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you see leftovers from a previous cell it is because it is being reused and values aren't reset. If am following your code correctly it is likely something like this.

```
else if([currentHandout.content[indexPath.row  - 3] isKindOfClass: [objHandoutSimpleQuestion class]]){
        cellId =@"CellHandoutSimpleQuestion";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UILabel *questionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        questionLabel.text = questionText;

        UITextView *theTextView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        theTextView.tag = indexPath.row + 100;
            theTextView.delegate = self;


        theTextView.text = @"";

        //or set text if there is text to set



        ..
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me, when add text to one of the text views it still appears in one four cells below in addition to the one I entered it in and then other cell further below of the same type.

Comment: The cell with the duplicate text is @"CellHandoutSimpleQuestion" correct? If so it could be something you are doing under the line I added.

Comment: I tried again by creating this  **NSString * emptyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];** and setting the text to it and it worked.  I replace that will @"" as you said and it worked, not sure why it didn't the first time sorry.  Anyway, it still doesn't work correctly. When the cell is scrolled off the screen it loses whatever I type in, but I think the solution above will fix that.  Thank you for your suggestion, it pointed the way.

Comment: Yup. Ironically I solved what you asked and Pablo solved what would then be your next issue and that is getting the text back. That is why I added the comment saying //or set the text if there is text to set. Either way glad you got it working correctly that is the important thing =)